# Why does plink or bash not recognize command on first line of remote commands file?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, powershell, plink

I am using plink and pageant in PowerShell to connect to and run commands on a linux machine via ssh. Within the PS script I am attempting to provide a unix script file to plink as follows.

test.ps1:

```
$remote_cmd_file = "test.sh"

pageant $priv_key
plink $usr@$dom -batch -m $remote_cmd_file
```

(Variables $usr, $dom, and $priv_key are properly defined but not given here.)

The "test.sh" file's entire contents are:

```
cd /
pwd
```

I get the output:

```
plink : bash: ï»¿cd: command not found
At C:\workspace\test.ps1:8 char:1
+ plink $usr@$dom -batch -m $remote_cmd_file
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bash: ï»¿cd: command not found:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

/my/remote/home/directory
```

so clearly the second line executed but the first did not.

If I start "test.sh" with a blank line instead, I get a similar message but both commands execute. I get the output:

```
plink : bash: ï»¿: command not found
At C:\workspace\test.ps1:8 char:1
+ plink $usr@$dom -batch -m $remote_cmd_file
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bash: ï»¿: command not found:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

/
```

Finally, when I start the script with a line like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then I get

```
plink : bash: ï»¿#!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
At C:\workspace\test.ps1:8 char:1
+ plink $usr@$dom -batch -m $remote_cmd_file
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bash: ï»¿#!/bin...le or directory:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

/
```

but lines starting with # anywhere else in the script are correctly interpreted as comments and produce no output.

This seems like an issue with plink or perhaps bash, but I wasn't able to find any existing questions about it. As a workaround, it seems like I can make sure all of my commands execute by leaving the first line blank, but the warning is annoying and I am wondering what causes this quirk.

In case it's helpful, my eventual goal is to get this script to submit jobs on the remote machine via slurm, transforming some files, then within the same PowerShell script work with those files on the local machine where I can call various Windows programs on them from the command line.

Comment: `ï»¿` is [UTF-8 BOM while interpreted as CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding). See this: [*How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255993/10765659)

Comment: I hadn't thought much of those characters because I know plink can give some weird-looking output like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143684. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the shell script file itself, which began with a Byte Order Mark that interfered with interpretation of its first line. Creating a file that did not begin with that character resolved the issue.